# OAuth2 w/ Google Client API 1.8.1

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I have been using the Google Client API in a .NET web application - but need to update to the latest version (both to use the most recent code but also to lose the need for the DotNetOpenAuth.dll.)  The latest version (1.8.1) has a totally redesigned OAuth interface (using google.apis.auth) and I can't seem to even get started w/ it.

Previously I had written code that handled generating an AuthorizationURL (as needed) and creating IAuthenticator and IAuthorizationState objects - storing the refresh token in a sql database as needed.  I was also about to retrieve "UserInfo" about the user as needed (once authenticated.)

Now - I'm unclear on how to handle the generation of the AuthURL (do I have to do it 100% manually?) and how/what I need to pass to the BaseClientService.Initializer when working w/ client API (such as Google Drive.)

Also - previously I wrote methods to "store" and "retrieve" credentials from the database - now it seems I would need to write a class based on IDataStore?  But I'm not sure if this is even correct (let alone find a decent sample/doc anywhere.)

Finally - it doesn't seem like google.apis.auth handles anything w/ regards to UserInfo - I have to grab google.apis.oauth2 - but that .dll has even LESS documentation/sample code out there.

Any advice on where to start?  The google.apis sample code seems decent for performing basic api tasks but all the Oauth2 information is very basic, uses file data storage and seems glossed over.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're in SDK DLL hell, it might be worth considering throwing it all away and making your own OAuth http calls. You'll be surprised at just how simple it is.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, take a look at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth. All the documentation that you might need is there, and if something is missing let us know!

You are right, you already have an implementation of FileDataStore, and we are planning to create EFDataStore as well for the next release.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the "answer" - the link doesn't provide any detail on generating AuthorizationURLs (I'm guessing its assumed all that is handled prior), implementing a custom IDataStore, accessing UserInfo - or handling any of the process in something resembling a real life scenario (although I'm again guessing that this last part is due to a breakdown in my understanding.)  Is there ANYWHERE else to look for any "real world" web based details?

Comment: If you need UserInfo data you can add its scope ("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"). Regarding generating the authorization URL - If you work with installed application, you don't need to do anything. If you work with Web application - follow the instructions at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web_applications

Comment: Doesn't do me much good - as this is a webforms application - not a MVC app (actually - the existing Google API integration was done in a class library.)  I've been experimenting w/ GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker - and it redirects automatically - but it seems to use a fixed REDIRECT URL.

Comment: it seems like many simple/useful functions are hidden away.  I can generate an auth url using GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow - but there doesn't seem to be a way to "force" prompt for access w/o overriding the flow w/ a custom one.  Also - everything appears to be asynchronous - which makes sense but appears to present significant challenges when attempting a simply website based solution.

Comment: peleyal - since you've been so kind to answer my questions thus far - I'm hoping you can provide guidance on one item.  It revolves around the various async oauth2 calls that are part of the API.  What is the correct way to call them synchronously from a web application?  I've wrapped the async methods (which use await) w/ synchronous versions that return a value using ".Result."  This deadlocks unless I use ".ConfigureAwait(false)" - but I see cryptic warnings about NOT doing that...

Comment: Does this sample help you? https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Tasks.ASP.NET.SimpleOAuth2/Default.aspx.cs?repo=samples It is a ASP (not MVC) sample for the Tasks API. It uses sync calls...